# Dell all-in-one beeping 8 times, how can I disable it?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, dell-inspiron, all-in-one, beep-code

I have a Dell Inspiron 24 all-in-one model 3455 series and the display on it is cracked. You can't see anything on it.

Because of this, I want to use an external monitor, but Windows doesn't duplicate the display on boot, and instead extends them with the broken LCD being the main monitor.

So now I want to take out the ribbon cable connecting the display to the motherboard but when I do that, it beeps 8 times, which I know is the display failure code.

Is there any way I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just plug your broken screen back in, and do this at boot...

Windows key + P -> Arrow Down x 2 -> Enter

Should set "Second screen only"